# If I follow an answer / a question and it gets edited, will I receive a notification?

Tags: support, notifications, follow-posts

I started following an answer, which I then revised. But I didn't receive a notification for this revision.

Is it because I made this revision? If others revise this answer, will I receive notifications? Also, does it apply to questions as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/843029):

> After you have followed a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices. You will not receive notifications for any action that you performed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

You aren't notified of your own edits, because that would be pointless: you already know about them.

As a demonstration, you should have received a notification of the small edit I just made to that answer.

Comment: Great, I received your revision notification, does this apply to questions as well? I.e. Following a question will receive revision notifications except your own revisions.

Comment: @WenfangDu yes, the behavior is the same for both questions and answers.

Comment: The caveat being that following the question doesn't automatically follow the answers. You have to follow them separately. 